# Getting error if user types a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how I can get my code to not crash if a user types anything other than a number for input. I thought that my else statement would cover it but I get an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python33/Skechers.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       run_prog = input()   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 's' is not defined

In this instance I typed the letter "s".

Below is the portion of the code that gives me the issue. The program runs flawlessly other than if you give it letters or symbols.

I want it to print "Invalid input" instead of crashing if possible.

Is there a trick that I have to do with another elif statement and isalpha function?

```
while times_run == 0:
    print("Would you like to run the calculation?")
    print("Press 1 for YES.")
    print("Press 2 for NO.")
    run_prog = input()

    if run_prog == 1:
        total()
        times_run = 1

    elif run_prog == 2:
            exit()

    else:
        print ("Invalid input")
        print(" ")
```

I tried a few variations of this with no success.

```
elif str(run_prog):
    print ("Invalid: input")
    print(" ")
```

I appreciate any feedback even if it is for me to reference a specific part of the python manual.

Thanks!

Comment: Odd. This appears to be Python3, but it also appears to be treating your input (presumably of the letter `s`) as input rather than a string. Just to see what happens, could you try replacing `input` with `raw_input`? (Incidentally, since the error occurs on the `run_prog = input()` line, don't look for the error in the later lines or wonder why the else didn't fix it)

Comment: It gives me a syntax error when I do that.

Comment: A SyntaxError or a NameError?

Comment: A SyntaxError. I can do raw_input on earlier versions with no issue.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the full traceback of that SyntaxError for me?

Comment: Only I still get the error when typing a symbol or letter.

Comment: Ok, I installed 2.7 and now raw_input works in 3.3.2... I don't know if this is because I installed 2.7, or because I didn't put it in correctly. My issue has been completely solved!

Comment: I bet you a cookie the thing you think is Python "3.3.2" is actually 2.7.  `sys.version` will tell you.

Comment: You are correct. I found that it was opening in 2.7 console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what you think, your script is *not* being run in Python 3.x. Somewhere on your system you have Python 2.x installed and the script is running in that, causing it to use 2.x's insecure/inappropriate `input()` instead.

Comment: Ok, I just installed 2.7 and now raw_input works in 3.3.2... I don't know if this is because I installed 2.7, or because I didn't put it in correctly. My issue has been completely solved!

Comment: `raw_input()` does not exist in 3.3.2. Your script is being run by the 2.7 binary.

Comment: Awesome. I will read up on that as I am now curious about the details. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

The error message you showed indicates that `input()` tried to evaluate the string typed as a Python expression.  This in turn means you're not actually using Python 3; `input` only does that in 2.x.  Anyhow, I strongly recommend you do it this way instead, as it makes explicit the kind of input you want.

```
while times_run == 0:
    sys.stdout.write("Would you like to run the calculation?\n"
                     "Press 1 for YES.\n"
                     "Press 2 for NO.\n")
    try:
        run_prog = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    except ValueError:
        run_prog = 0

    if not (1 <= run_prog <= 2):
        sys.stdout.write("Invalid input.\n")
        continue

    # ... what you have ...
```

Comment: `input()` was fixed in 3.x.

Comment: This is not true in Python 3. See [here](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ... *checks* ... So it was.  I guess the OP must not actually be using 3.x, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
while times_run == 0:
print("Would you like to run the calculation?")
print("Press 1 for YES.")
print("Press 2 for NO.")
run_prog = input()

if run_prog == 1:
    total()
    times_run = 1

elif run_prog == 2:
        exit()

elif run_prog not in [1,2]:
        print('Please enter a number between 1 and 2.')
```

If the user writes `s` the text `Please enter a number between 1 and 2` will appear